# Chocolate, Vanilla, Strawberry, Mint, Rocky Road, Bubblegum

Tags: word, science

Up and down. Not right or left.

Top and bottom. Neither side.

The remaining ones are strange. Would think 'twas charmed.

What are we?

Hint:

> The title is a pun on the correct title (but would be too easy if I used the hidden title.) Solve it for a clue. Some science vocabulary required.

Comment: Sure is an interesting *spin* on a classic puzzle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

> Quarks

Context:

> There are 6 types (AKA flavours as hinted in the title) of quarks: up, down, top, bottom (not left, right or something), strange and charm.

Answer (score 9):

I think the answer is

> Quarks (or flavours of quark)

The title refers to

> The term 'flavours' is used for different types of quark which are up, down, top, bottom, strange and charm as referenced in the text. In the case of the title, the flavours are flavours of ice cream.